# Can I change the interval of the pitch shift while playing audio using tone.js?

Tags: javascript, tone.js

I'll show you my code

```
audio_music = new Audio();
var track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio_music);

//Import music files from other sources into base64 form.
audio_music.src = "data:audio/ogg;base64,"+ data.music;

var splitter = audioContext.createChannelSplitter(6);
var merger = audioContext.createChannelMerger(2);
track.connect(splitter);

//omitted in addition to 0 and 1 due to repetition of the similar content
gainNode0 = audioContext.createGain(); gainNode0.gain.setValueAtTime((musicvolume*0.1), audioContext.currentTime);
gainNode1 = audioContext.createGain(); gainNode1.gain.setValueAtTime((musicvolume*0.1), audioContext.currentTime);

splitter.connect(gainNode0, 0);
splitter.connect(gainNode1, 1);

var pitchshift0 = new Tone.PitchShift(pitch);
var pitchshift1 = new Tone.PitchShift(pitch);

Tone.connect(gainNode0, pitchshift0);
Tone.connect(gainNode1, pitchshift1);

Tone.connect(pitchshift0, merger, 0, 0);
Tone.connect(pitchshift1, merger, 0, 1);

Tone.connect(merger, audioContext.destination);
```

I am not familiar with the use of audioContext and tone.js, so I don't know if I understand correctly, but my intention is to separate input sources with six channels and process them in the order of gain adjustment, pitch shift, and marge, respectively.

This will do everything else, but you can't change the value of the pitch shift during playback.

I want a way to function similar to the setValueAtTime used in GainNode in pitch shift.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pitch by setting the pitch parameter:

```js
pitchshift0.pitch = -12 // Semitone to shift the pitch to.
```

If you want to set this at a specific time during playback, you can use the Transport class to schedule this:

```js
Tone.Transport.schedule(() => pitchshift0.pitch = -12, time /* The transport time you want to schedule it at */);
```